# Failing to read xml file with php's simplexml_load_file in localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: php, xml, xampp

I am trying to do something as simple as reading an XML file from php using XAMPP in MAC OS 10.9. For some reason I can't understand I cannot get a consistent response from the server (localhost). Sometimes it works, and I get the response printed on the browser; but most of the times I simply don't get an answer from the server.

Here is what google chrome tells me when the server does not respond:
"No data received.
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE."

Here's the code (this is as simple as it can get):

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $xmlCustomers = simplexml_load_file("customers.xml");
    print_r($xmlCustomers);
?>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<channel>
    <item>
         <name>Joao</name>
         <phone>961111111</phone>
         <email>joao@mail.com</email>
    </item>
    <item>
         <name>Joana</name>
         <phone>962222222</phone>
         <email>joana@email.com</email>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Somebody knows how can I solve this? is this a problem of XAMPP?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and found the solution. Well, solution, it's more of a work around but I makes everything work again.

Instead of loading the XML file directly into SimpleXML you can also parse the content into a string and then load it into SimpleXML, which did the trick for me:

```
/* Read XML file */
$xml_file_content = file_get_contents($xml_file);

/* Parse XML */
$parsed_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_file_content);
```